# issue with cross-site cookies: how to set cookie from backend to frontend

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, cookies, fastapi, samesite

I'm currently developing my first webapp, frontend with `React` and backend with `FastAPI`.

I'm trying to test it out jointly with Chrome-- see if the frontend makes the correct API calls to backend, and display the results. I've been having problems with cookies, and I'd like help. Apologies in advance for the long post – I've been going through many resources past couple of days, and at this point I'm unsure what's relevant and what's not.

- Frontend on `localhost:8080`
- Backend on `http://127.0.0.1:8000`
- Proper settings for CORS (I believe) with the following `FastAPI` backend code:

```
app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost:8080"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

**Situation:** Frontend makes a `GET` request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/abc` on backend, the backend sets a cookie.

/*====================

*Attempt 1:*

set cookie with the following backend code:

```
response.set_cookie(key="abcCookieKey", value="abcCookieValue")
```

and make the `GET` request with the following frontend JS code:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/abc', {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
        })
```

*Result with attempt 1:*

on the `Console` tab of Chrome, I get the following warning:

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://127.0.0.1/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

and on the network tab I get the following message when examining the `set-cookie` response header:

```
This Set-Cookie was blocked because it has the "SameSite=Lax" attribute but came from a cross-site response which was not the response to a top-level navigation.
```

====================*/

...so I do some research, and come up with

/*====================

*Attempt 2:*

set cookie with the following backend code:

```
response.set_cookie(key="abcCookieKey", value="abcCookieValue", samesite="none", secure=True)
```

and make the `GET` request with the same frontend JS code.

*Result with attempt 2:*

on the `Console` tab of Chrome, I get the exact same warning as from attempt 1, even though the response header has a `set-cookie` with `Samesite=none; Secure`. Additionally, the header has the following warning

```
This Set-Cookie was blocked because it had the "Secure" attribute but was not received over a secure connection.
```

====================*/

..so I try to use `https` and come up with:

/*====================

*Attempt 3:*
Everything the same as attempt #2, except in my JS fetch code, I use `fetch('https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/abc ...`

 and then I get the following warning on my backend running with `uvicorn`: `WARNING:  Invalid HTTP request received.`

====================*/

Questions:

1. am I missing something with attempt #2? surely there must be an easy way to set a cookie from backend to frontend without worrying about https?
2. if I don't have a choice but to use `https`, how do I locally run a backend server that can be accessed with `https`? The research I did made it seem like it was a complicated/time-consuming process. (But, to be fair, my understanding of web-dev/all things network is very limited).

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: the short answer is no, I didn't solve it. I just ended up using Safari to get around it, then checked that it works on Chrome after deployment.

Comment: I resolved it, if you need I can post the answer

Comment: how did you resolved it Shashan ?

Comment: Please post the answer @ShashanSooriyahetti as you can see there are many of us who would like to know.

Comment: @consoleart sorry your comment did not reach me as you have failed to mention me man. I have added the answer

Comment: @Marisha I have added the answer as you guys requested feel free to ask anthing

Comment: Future readers might find these related answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75048778/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74407063/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) helpful.

Answer (score 11):

I will try to give the concept.

First please know that I'm using a Backend which is developed from `SailsJS` and a Frontend which is developed from `AngularJS` and Apps that connect to backend which are developed from using `Angular9`.

I am using http only cookie for the frontend (a CMS) to grant permission to add content to users that are logged in. HTTP only cookie will be set to them on authentication success.

Please note that there is a tricky part to http cookies and backend and frontend both serve different URLs just like in the scenario presented.

Points:

1. So when in development you have to host your backend and frontend under same IP.
   ex. my backend : 192.168.8.160:1337, frontend: 192.168.8.160:81.
   different ports same ip.
2. this is not the scenario when it goes to production you can have any domain :)
3. you have to allow CORS in backend and have your frontend ip:port under accepted origins.
4. Implementation, you have to identify your environment, in my case,

```js
if (sails.config.environment === 'development'){
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie',[`token=${token};  Path=/;HttpOnly; maxAge=86400000;SameSite=false;`]);
} else {
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie',[`token=${token};  Path=/;HttpOnly; maxAge=86400000;SameSite=None;Secure=true;`]);
}
```

Please note in above code in development environment you need `SameSite=false` therefore you need to have the same ip because we cannot have `SameSite=None` because it would require to have `Secure=true` and it would then require HTTPS. It would be a headache to achieve it in development mode.

That's it folks. If you get this right you can achieve this.

Comment: Thank you so much...This ans. saved my bunch of time.I work with Django + React(JWT Auth.).when I set Httponly cookie in backend but it is not set in frontend api request.

Comment: I have been trying to solve the exact same issue for a whole day now. This answer did it for me. I still don't understand what is the difference between samesite false and same samesite none. I thought I they were the exact same thing. Anyway this will do for now

Comment: @KarimKamel glad it helped, you can give a upvote ;) 
the difference between SameSite=none means you can have this cookie for other domains as well but you need https to do that but because you cannot achieve that in development  environment we use SameSite=false we can use the same IP with different ports rather than using different IPs.  Because it is using same IP you don't need HTTPS

Comment: If you are using create react app and wanted to use HTTPS, just add HTTPS=true to your start script in package.json:

scripts: {
    "start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start"
}

Comment: @Rem good one, angular also supports HTTPS with ng s --ssl

Comment: @hainabaraka you should promptly mark this as the accepted answer, a truly brilliant explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can completely disable this feature by going to "chrome://flags" and disabling "Cookies without SameSite must be secure". However, this will disable it for all sites, so it will be less secure when you aren't developing too.

Comment: this didnt work for, i still am getting the "secure "error

Answer (score 0):

Remove the wildcards since wildcarding is not allowed with `allow_credentials=True` :

```
app.add_middleware(
  CORSMiddleware,
  allow_origins=['http://localhost:8080'],
  allow_credentials=True,
  allow_methods=["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"], /* include additional methods as per the application demand */
  allow_headers=["Content-Type","Set-Cookie"], /* include additional headers as per the application demand */
)
```

Set `samesite` to `none` while setting the cookie (modern browsers demand it):

```
/* `secure=True` is optional and used for secure https connections */
response.set_cookie(key='token_name', value='token_value', httponly=True, secure=True, samesite='none')
```

If client side is using Safari, disable `Prevent cros-site tracking` in `Preferences`. That's It!