# Cookie is not created when calling the endpoint in FastAPI

Tags: python, cookies, fastapi, starlette, cookie-httponly

I have encountered an issue, as I have to create a cookie in the backend, which I will later use to send a request from the frontend. Both apps are on the same domain. This is the general idea behind it: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/secure-frontend-authorization-67ae11953723.

**Frontend** - Sending `GET` request to Backend

```py
@app.get('/')
async def homepage(request: Request, response_class=HTMLResponse):
    keycloak_code = 'sksdkssdk'
    data = {'code': keycloak_code}
    url_post = 'http://127.0.0.1:8002/keycloak_code'
    post_token=requests.get(url=url_post, json = data ) 
      return 'Sent'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='local.me.me', port=7999,debug=True)
```

**Backend**

```py
@app.get("/keycloak_code")
def get_tokens(response: Response, data: dict):
    code = data['code']
    print(code)
....

    requests.get(url='http://local.me.me:8002/set') 
    return True

@app.get("/set")
async def createcookie(response: Response):
    r=response.set_cookie(key='tokic3', value='helloworld', httponly=True)
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='local.me.me', port=8002, log_level="debug")
```

When I open the browser and access `http://local.me.me:8002/set`, I can see that the cookie is created.
But when I make a `GET` request from my frontend to backend to the same URL, the request is received—as I can see in the terminal—but the backend does not create the cookie. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

I have tried different implementations from FastAPI docs, but none has similar use cases.

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` and `localhost` (or `local.me.me` in your case) are two **different** domains (and hence, different [origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin)). Hence, when making a request you need to use the **same** domain you used for creating the cookie, in order to pass it to the backend. For example, if the cookie was created for `local.me.me` domain, you should then use that domain when sending the request. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74106637/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) for more details and examples.

You also seem to have a second FastAPI application (listenning on a different port) acting as your frontend (as you noted). If that's what you are trying to do, you would need to use [`Session` Objects](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) in Python `requests` library, or preferably, use a [`Client` instance](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#why-use-a-client) from the [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org/) library, in order to persist cookies across requests. The advantage of `httpx` is that it offers an *asynchronous* API as well, using the [`httpx.AsyncClient()`](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#making-async-requests). You could find more details and examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73672334/17865804).