# can't set cookie in custom local domain

Tags: cookies, localhost, fastapi

I setting cookie using FastApi

```
response.set_cookie(key="rf_t", value=access_token, httponly=False, expires=120)
```

And its works perfect on "localhost:<any_port>" local domain

but I need subdomains and cross subdomain cookies so I found out you can change hosts file at \Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

and created couple of domains with subdomains like so:

```
127.0.0.1 main.shop.localhost
127.0.0.1 admin.shop.localhost
127.0.0.1 store.shop.localhost

127.0.0.1 shop.localhost
```

- and cookie doesn't set for all of them, JSON responses come from server, but cookie doesn't set, it only sets when I'm
  using basic localhost domain

im using vue 3 vite on front, and setting dev domain and port in vite.config.js like so

```
server: {
    port: 5000,
    host: "shop.localhost"
  },
```

I guess it has something to do with chrome policy, because its not https, but is there any way I can use local subdomains, and be able to set cross cookies (or any cookies) for them?

Thanks you a lot my fellow developers!

Comment: Please have a look at the following answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74407063/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804)

Comment: @Chris that helped Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting api server host to the same local domain (`api.shop.localhost`) as front (`app.shop.localhost`), made it work!
shout-out to [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17865804/chris)

For further details, please have a look at the following answers:

1. [Cookie is not created when calling the endpoint in FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74407063/17865804)
2. [FastAPI is not returning cookies to React frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804)
3. [How to redirect from one domain to another and set cookies or headers for the other domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804)