# FastAPI: How to enable CORS only for specific endpoints?

Tags: python, cors, fastapi

The example below will enalbe CORS for all the endpoints in the application. How to enable CORS only for **specific** endpoints, or just an individual endpoint, using FastAPI?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_credentials=False,
    allow_methods=["GET","DELETE"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
    max_age=0
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [Sub application](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/#sub-applications-mounts) with **only** the endpoints you wish to be accessible from a different [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) than the backend, and add the [`CORSMiddleware`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/#use-corsmiddleware) to that sub app **only**.

Note that, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804), using the `'*'` wildcard in the `allow_origins` argument (as demonstrated in your question)—instead of specifying specific origins as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804)—would mean that **all origins** are allowed; **however**,  at the cost of *excluding* everything that involves credentials, such as *cookies*, *authorization headers*, etc; and hence, setting the `allow_credentials` argument to `True` (see [`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) response header documentation) would have no effect, and you still wouldn't be able to send/receive credentials (such as those described above) between the client and the server, when a [cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) request is performed (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#requests_with_credentials:%7E:text=If%20a%20request%20includes%20a%20credential%20(most%20commonly%20a%20Cookie%20header)%20and%20the%20response%20includes%20an%20Access%2DControl%2DAllow%2DOrigin%3A%20*%20header%20(that%20is%2C%20with%20the%20wildcard)%2C%20the%20browser%20will%20block%20access%20to%20the%20response%2C%20and%20report%20a%20CORS%20error%20in%20the%20devtools%20console) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) for more details).

### Working Example

The `/sub` endpoint from `subapi` (sub application) in the example below can be accessed at http://127.0.0.1:8000/subapi/sub

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()
subapi = FastAPI()

# specify the origins from which you wish the backend (subapi) to be accessible 
origins = ['http://localhost:3000']  

subapi.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=['*'],
    allow_headers=['*'],
)


@app.get('/app')
def read_main():
    return {'message': 'Hello World from main app'}
    
 
@subapi.get('/sub')
def read_sub():
    return {'message': 'Hello World from sub API'}


app.mount('/subapi', subapi)
```