# CORS error , even access-control-allow-origin is allowed for the domain

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cors, fastapi

When accessing `http://localhost:8088/api/` from `https://my.example.com`, I have this CORS error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8088/api/' from origin 'https://my.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

OK, It is popular error for CORS, so I checked the server setting.

```bash
curl -X POST -F file=@test_material/0_for_django_testcase.png  -F metadata='{"test":"test"}' -i localhost:8088/api/ -H "Origin: https://my.example.com
```

It return this header, but It looks like `https://my.example.com` is allowed...?

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
date: Mon, 10 Jul 2023 12:53:50 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 510
content-type: application/json
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Disposition
access-control-allow-origin: https://my.example.com
vary: Origin
```

If so, why does this error happen?

I tested on both Chrome and Firefox.

Any help appreciated.

**Next Trial**

Thanks to [@jub0bs comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76653996/cors-error-even-access-control-allow-origin-is-allowed-for-the-domain#comment135146788_76653996), I tried to check with

```bash
curl -X OPTIONS -F file=@test_material/0_for_django_testcase.png  -F metadata='{"test":"test"}' -i localhost:8088/api/ -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -H "Origin: https://my.example.com"
```

It returns,

```
date: Mon, 10 Jul 2023 14:40:27 GMT
server: uvicorn
vary: Origin
access-control-allow-methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
access-control-max-age: 600
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://my.example.com
content-length: 2
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

It looks like accepting `OPTIONS` too...

**FastAPI Server setting is like this**

```py
    def add_cors_middleware(app: FastAPI):
        app.add_middleware(
            CORSMiddleware,
            allow_origins=[
                "http://localhost:8021",
                "https://my.example.com",
            ],
            allow_credentials=True,
            allow_methods=["*"],
            allow_headers=["*"],
            expose_headers=["Content-Disposition"],
        )
```

Comment: The error message indicates that the problem lies in the preflight response. Therefore, that `curl` command you're using to diagnose the problem should, at the very least, use the `OPTIONS` method. You should also run it with `-H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST"`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I update the article about trying to check the method with `OPTIONS`

Comment: You might find the following answers helpful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75048778/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804)

Comment: I cannot reconcile the error message with the headers present in the preflight response. There must be something you're not telling us...

Comment: Also, `https://https://my.example.com` in your FastAPI config is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you @Chris I read the articles, this is good study for me.

Comment: @job0bs Thank you for your help. I finally found out this is related with chrome cache. I use secret mode, it works without error, in normal browser mode it shows error.

Answer (score 0):

replace this header's value access-control-allow-origin: https://my.example.com
from django server and add localhost:your_server_port_where_server_is_running instead of your website link

Comment: This api server running on port:8088 is in container-A and `reactjs` and `django`  running on port:8021 is in container-B, in this case, `access-control-allow-origin` should be `http://localhosg:8021`? Browser doesn't know this is on localhost:8021

Comment: I added 'http://localhost:8021', but in vain....

Comment: http://localhost:8088 Try to add this and try to add multiple origins may cause you to get rid of your error

Comment: another possible solution is to disable cors from your api call

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue with one of our `nodejs` `expressjs` code

for `OPTIONS` alone you write a response with `200` in your application side

Which means, when OPTIONS coming as part the request your server side code will simply return

```
HTTP 200 OK
```